# Getting either exception "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: METASTORE_CLIENT_SOCKET_LIFETIME" or "Required field 'client_protocol' is unset!"

Tags: java, apache-spark, jdbc, hive, spark-structured-streaming

I am using Structured Streaming of Spark 2.1 (which internally uses Hive 1.2.1 jars).  I am trying to develop ForEachWriter for Hive to write streaming data to Hive through JDBC connector.

On my cluster I have Hive 1.1.0.

If I use Hive jdbc jar of version 1.2.1, then I am getting below exception because of mismatch in client & server version of Hive :

```
Required field 'client_protocol' is unset!
```

And if I use Hive jdbc jar of version 1.1.0, then I am getting exception in Spark as below :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: METASTORE_CLIENT_SOCKET_LIFETIME
```

Its coming while initializing `HiveContex`t in `SparkSession`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and found [HIVE-9508](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9508). I suggest you upgrade hive to 1.2.1 or later.